# How to properly format/nest while statements to validate input data type and range in Java?

Tags: java, loops, nested

//Creates a scanner object to read input from the user 
      Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

```
  //Asks the user for the month of birth 
  System.out.print("Enter your Month of Birth: ");

  //Utilizes a while loop to verify input type and prompt re-enter if necessary 
  while (!scan.hasNextInt()) 
  {
    System.out.print("Invalid data type: Please enter an Integer: ");
    scan.next();
  }

  //If input is correct type, uses the input 
  BirthMonth = scan.nextInt();

  //Utilizes the while loop to verify and ask user to re-enter month input if incorrect
  while (BirthMonth<1 || BirthMonth >12)
    {
      System.out.print("Invalid Month. Re-Enter your Month of Birth: ");
      BirthMonth = scan.nextInt();
    }
```

The problem arises when an invalid range is entered. The program prompts the user to re-enter an appropriate integer within the specified range. If the user re-enters an invalid data type at this point (such as ten) the program crashes. I believe this is happening because once the correct data type has been verified the program then moves on to verify the range, and does not re-check the correct data type.

I am thinking that this problem will be easily fixed by nesting the while statements so that each time new input is entered the program will recheck data type again. I am having trouble properly formatting/nesting the while statements. Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

`int BirthMonth = 0;
while (true) 
{ 
 if( (!scan.hasNextInt()) {
  System.out.print("Invalid data type: Please enter an Integer: "); 
  scan.next();
 } else {
  Birthmonth = scan.nextInt(); 
  if(BirthMonth<1 || BirthMonth >12) { 
   System.out.print("Invalid Month. Re-Enter your Month of Birth: "); 
   scan.next();
  } else 
     break; 
} 
}`

Answer (score 0):

Add a `do`, and something like

```
int BirthMonth = 1; // <-- should really be birthMonth
do { // <--
  if (BirthMonth != 1) {
    System.out.print("Invalid Month. Re-Enter your Month of Birth: ");
  }
  //Asks the user for the month of birth 
  System.out.print("Enter your Month of Birth: ");

  //Utilizes a while loop to verify input type and prompt re-enter if necessary 
  while (!scan.hasNextInt()) 
  {
    System.out.print("Invalid data type: Please enter an Integer: ");
    scan.next();
  }

  //If input is correct type, uses the input 
  BirthMonth = scan.nextInt();

  //Utilizes the while loop to verify and ask user to re-enter month input 
  //if incorrect
} while (BirthMonth<1 || BirthMonth >12); // <-- end it here.
```